# How can I retain an ImageIcon's file name for later reference?

Tags: java, string, swing, jbutton, imageicon

Given this code,

```
tableButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("80F_FG2015.GIF"));
```

how would I get that `String` to be returned to me so I can compare it to another `String`?

Comment: Have you tried [getSelectedIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getSelectedIcon%28%29) or even [getIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getIcon%28%29)?

Comment: Did you mean the name of the image?

Comment: there would be no selection of the button however it is merely a way to display them

Comment: and yes the name of the image @Sujay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way to solve your problem is creating

```
tableButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("80F_FG2015.GIF", "80F_FG2015.GIF"));
```

The second argument is the description. And ImageIcon.toString() method returns the description. So you can very well compare this description with the description from another image icon

You can get back the description as follows:

```
System.out.println(((ImageIcon)tableButton.getIcon()).getDescription()); 
//or
System.out.println(((ImageIcon)tableButton.getIcon()).toString());
```

Comment: So would the description for this button be "ImageIcon("80F_FG2015.GIF")"? or would it just be "80F_FG2015.GIF"?

Comment: whatever you put as the second argument. Since I put 80F_FG2015.GIF as the description, toString() would return this as a result

Comment: oh i see but just like the previous answer this would work if I had not already created close to 2000 buttons with the configuration i had given in my question

Comment: yeah i started to do that already once im done ill you know if it works and ill approve your answer

Comment: @Sujay in order to call the method would the code be `tableButton.ImageIcon.toString()` or `ImageIcon.toString()` ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Life saver

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using Reflection :

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(pathImg);
    JButton jButton1 = new JButton(icon);
    Field field = null;
    try {
        Class<? extends ImageIcon> clazz = ((ImageIcon) jButton1.getIcon()).getClass();
        //Get the field "filename" where the Image path is stored. 
        field = clazz.getDeclaredField("filename");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String path = (String) field.get(icon);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AAMainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AAMainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AAMainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AAMainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new class that extends JButton.  Store the string in the class.

```
class MyButton extends JButton
{
    private String filename;

    public MyButton(String filename)
    {
        super(new ImageIcon(filename));
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getFilename()
    {
        return filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to do this but there is close to 2000 lines of codes to pick the proper image to put on the JButton i would have to go in a change a everyone of those instances and change JButton to MyButton but this would definitely work if i had not already written the other code. Thanks.

Comment: Many IDE's support such re-factoring.